# How can i set the focus to vue flat-pickr component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flatpickr

I'm not able to set the focus to the vue flat-pickr component.  For example, if I have the following:

```
<flat-pickr 
     v-model="date_opened"
     id="file_opened"
     :config="flatpickr_config_date"
     :disabled="disableFileInfo" />
```

I cannot set the focus to that field using:   document.getElementById("file_opened").focus();
I am able to set the focus to other input elements, but not the flat-pickr element.
Is there another approach I should be using?
Thanks

Comment: `I cannot set the focus to that field` what happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a ref to the flat picker and then calling focus via the ref might solve the problem

```
this.$refs.flatPicker.focus()
```